# Oracle:Select Most Recent based on many-many relation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have following two tables **card_accounts** and **account_transaction**.

```
create table card_accounts(card_number number(16),account_number number(10),status char(1));


Insert into card_accounts(card_number,account_number,status)values(123456,000001,'A');
Insert into card_accounts(card_number,account_number,status)values(123456,000002,'A');
Insert into card_accounts(card_number,account_number,status)values(223456,000003,'A');
Insert into card_accounts(card_number,account_number,status)values(223456,000004,'A');
Insert into card_accounts(card_number,account_number,status)values(33456,000004,'A');
Insert into card_accounts(card_number,account_number,status)values(523456,000007,'A');

create table account_transaction(account_number number(16),transactionId number(10),created_date DATE);


Insert into account_transaction(account_number,transactionId,created_date)values(000001,543678,TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
Insert into account_transaction(account_number,transactionId,created_date)values(000002,543679,TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:34', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
Insert into account_transaction(account_number,transactionId,created_date)values(000003,543680,TO_DATE('2003/05/03 18:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
Insert into account_transaction(account_number,transactionId,created_date)values(000004,543681,TO_DATE('2003/05/03 17:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
Insert into account_transaction(account_number,transactionId,created_date)values(000007,543682,TO_DATE('2003/05/03 21:02:44', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

I would like to retrieve account_number which have more recent transaction based on following criteria.When I use **card_number as key**,check if the card_number is associated with two account_number exactly if yes go to account_transaction and return party with most recent created_date on it.If card_number have more than two accounts or less than two accounts do not do anything.

Input:
[image][image]

**Expected Output when I pass card_number= 123456**

[image]

When I pass other card_numbers do not retreive anything because it failed to met criteria

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . .

```
select ca.*
from (select ca.card_number, act.*,  -- or whatever columns you want
             row_number() over (partition by ca.card_number order by act.created_date desc) as seqnum
      from (select ca.*, count(*) over (partition by ca.card_number) as cnt
            from card_accounts ca
           ) ca join
           account_transaction act
           on act.account_number = ca.account_number
      where ca.cnt = 2
     ) ca
where seqnum = 1;
```

The innermost subquery counts the number of accounts per number, which the `where ca.cnt = 2` filters to exactly two.  The middle subquery gets the most recent transaction for a given number.

Note:  If you want to filter for a particular number, then you can do that in the innermost subquery.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f074be681351271da9ff4c4a335e9684) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I passed card_number to to innermost query but got ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined but got ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @Rocky4Ever . . . That is just the `*`s in the subquery.  I added a db<>fiddle showing this working.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.....Here when I send card_number= 223456 return nothing ,because 223456 is associated with 00003 and 00004 and in turn 00004 associated to another card_number.But the above query returns result even for 223456